# How do I replace all whitespace values to Null in all columns at SQLITE3?

Tags: sqlite

I'm sorry I don't have code because I really don't know / didn't find how this is possible.

I've created a database from big TXT files that were separated by character length, making so that if the limit for - let's say - address field was 200 chars, but for 1 value it only had 50, the other 150 will be whitespace...example:

```
"                                                                        221 Baker Street, NY, NY"
```

Now, I have this 117gb database that I'm trying to lower the size (VACUUM did not work). I'm wondering if there is a way to **update all columns by trim() all values**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either :

- [Ltrim](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-ltrim/) to remove leading spaces
- [Rtrim](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-rtrim/) to remove trailing spaces
- [Trim](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-ltrim/) to remove leading and trailing spaces

Example:

```
UPDATE Thetable
SET column1=ltrim(column1, ' '), 
    column2=ltrim(column2, ' '), 
    column3=ltrim(column3, ' ')
```

Comment: Oh, so I can pass the same column as what I want to replace To.. that.. makes so much sense, thanks

Comment: yes this is the same approach in all programming languages...